# Compiled file not created in shared hosting server Laravel 5.1

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

I am new in Laravel and I have some problem in Laravel 5.1. I work on a GoDaddy shared hosting server. When I create a new view and upload it to the server and try to access this page it shows a blank page.

After long time I found out that Laravel created a view file inside `storage/framework/views/` with some encryption md5 name.

How to create this file. I have no ssh access to run `php artisan serve` and access and create runtime.

Please help me how can I create this view by using `http://example.com/xxzxxzx`

Comment: it's permission issue, i bet. laravel storage need to have **permission 775**, rwxrwx,r-x.

Comment: @Tezla you are really grate man , thnx again it worked :)

Comment: @HasiburRahaman Gives us an update on your progress within your questions.

Comment: @RyanFung sure ,I have no right now, if i face any problem i will,

Comment: Answer the question if solved. :)